# Boiler Relay Help

Tags: relay, connector

I am trying to figure out where the problem is on a boiler issue I’m having.  I have attached a wiring ladder diagram.

The old relay started chattering and making small visible sparks when heat was called by the thermostat and the boiler would not fire up.  I replaced it with a new OEM relay and still would not work. I removed the relay and jumped the 2 switching relay connectors and left the relay coil connector open. When I turn on the service shutoff switch the boiler fires until the temperature limit switch trips or I close the power manually. The thermostat has no effect on the operation in this setup which seems correct to me. If I test for voltage between the plug in connectors on the receptacle for the relay, I get 120 V across the hot loop and 28 V off both of LV circuits, the relay tests for continuity across the coil contacts and reads 14 ohms resistance.

I want to fix this issue so the thermostat will control the circuits again and I don’t have to operate it manually.

What can I test next to figure out why the relay won’t close the two circuits?

[image]

Comment: jumper across the thermostat ... node `R` to node `G`

Comment: @jsotola, that was the right path, thanks.  Tried your solution and the relay functioned and the boiler fired right up.  Troubleshot the thermostat loop and all the wiring and connections were good and they tested out at 28 V.  Found out I have a dreaded N72 error on a newer Google thermostat which is more of a software issue than the electrical setup.  Thanks.

Comment: the thermostat is the only switch that controls the relay, so it is the first thing to bypass